# how to make an infinate loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am just starting in javascript, I would like to have a toggle button that runs a function until it's pressed again. I have some code for the toggle:

```
const backgroundButton = document.getElementById("backgroundButton"); //getting button from HTML
let clickToggle = 0; //defining a veriable used to store the state of the button


backgroundButton.addEventListener("click", function(){   
    if (clickToggle == 0) {

        console.log('button was off');

        //start loop

        clickToggle = 1;
    }
    else {

        console.log('button was on');
        
        //stop loop
        
        clickToggle = 0;
    }
});
```

but, I don't know how to do an infinite loop, any help is greatly appreciated!

(PS: I know infinite loops crash, that's why I'm here)

Comment: There is a good resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: You don't want an infinite JS loop, as it blocks all the other execution on the page, including button clicks detection.

Comment: There are several options. `while(true)`, `for (i=0; i>=0; i++)`, `setTimeout/setInterval` ...

Comment: What do you want to do during this loop?

Comment: In this case, using setInterval/setTimeout is pretty much mandatory to not block the event loop which would prevent the call to the `stop` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`. A truly infinite loop would look like this:

```
while (true) doSomething();
```

But that is not what anyone wants, as it will block the user interface. Using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` you allow the event loop to continue to do its work.

I'll assume you want to repeat calling the function `doSomething` in this demo:

```js
const backgroundButton = document.getElementById("backgroundButton"); 
let timer = 0;
const output = document.getElementById("output");

backgroundButton.addEventListener("click", function(){   
    if (timer == 0) {
        console.log('button was off');
        //start loop
        timer = setInterval(doSomething, 50);        
    }
    else {
        console.log('button was on');
        //stop loop
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
});

function doSomething() {
    output.textContent = +output.textContent + 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="backgroundButton">Start/Stop</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Hopefully following with resolve you're required scenario.

```
let isEnabled = false;
let interval;

function clickFunction() {

    isEnabled = !isEnabled; // toggle enable flag

    if (isEnabled) {
        console.log('Set Interval', isEnabled)
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            console.log('Do some work.');
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        console.log('Clear Interval', isEnabled)
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}


<button onclick="clickFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for the infinite loop.

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('#toggle');

let hasBegun = false;
let anim;

const tick = () => {
    if (hasBegun) {
        document.querySelector('#output').textContent += '+';
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(tick)
};

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!hasBegun) {
        console.log('Starting');
        hasBegun = true;
        anim = requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    } else {
        console.log('Stopping');
        hasBegun = false;
        cancelAnimationFrame(anim);
        anim = null;
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="toggle">Start/Stop</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```